# Why is bootstrap-modal form opening but not visible?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have taken my project from another project, but after updating all the references in nuget. My bootstrap modal forms now seem to load, but they are not visible.

I've searched for similar issues but have not found any resolutions yet. The developer console in Chrome does not show up any script errors, and I am lost.

This is how I open the form:

```
{
   @*<div class="modal hide fade" id="AddCustomerRecordUI">*@
   <div class="modal fade" id="AddCustomerRecordUI">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
               &times;
            </button>
            <h3>Customer Record</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.BranchDetails.OrganisationId, new { Value = Model.OrgId })*@
            <div class="row-fluid AddCustomerRecordData">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" id="btnAddCustomerRecord" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

The content of the form comes from a partial view:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12">
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Address, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PersonalProof)
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PersonalProofId, Model.PersonalProof, "--Select Personal Proof--", new { @class = "input-block-level" })
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProofNumber)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ProofNumber, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProofOfEntitlement)
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProofOfEntitlementId, Model.ProofOfEntitlement, null, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
      @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EntitlementNumber)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EntitlementNumber, new { @class = "input-block-level" })
   </div>
</div>
```

And is open with the following javascript:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".customer-records", function(e) {
    var ui = $("#AddCustomerRecordUI")

    $.post("NewRecordBuilder", {
        id: "123"
    }, function(html) {
        ui.find(".AddCustomerRecordData").html(html);
        ui.modal("show");
    })
});
```

It appears the form opens but is invisible. Therefore, my web page looks normal, but I can't click on it.

I know the modal form is there though, as I can move the mouse pointer around, and the pointer will change over text and dropdownlists, and I can get a dropdownlist to show the items, I just can't see the form it is on?

Comment: any css rule blocking like `opacity:0` ?

Comment: Does it work if you try `ui.fadeToggle("modal");` or `ui.toggle("modal")`

Comment: Neither of JamesS suggestions work, and I can't see anywhere where the opacity is 0